# Upcoming Dates in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a workbook with two worksheets, one is Master List and the other is Summary.

On the Master List sheet, columns O, Q, and S contain ticket numbers. Columns P, R, and T contain the ticket date.

How could I use a formula or function that would allow me to do the following:

On the Summary tab, pull ticket numbers and dates where the date falls within the current week?

Comment: Why are the ticket numbers in different columns? Should they be in different columns on the Summary sheet as well?

Comment: They are in separate columns because that's how the data set was put together, out of my control. Multiple people are using a shared spreadsheet, so having the upcoming ticket numbers per day would be ideal. I think Linga's comment below will help yield how to do this, I just wasn't sure what functions or formulas would be the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below formula to get the current week dates. And try using vlookup or Index (match (), match ()) function to get the respective tickets.

Sunday of this current week:

=1-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY()

Monday of this current week:

=2-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY()

Tuesday of this current week:

=3-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY()

Wednesday of this current week:

=4-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY()

Thursday of this current week:

=5-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY()

Friday of this current week:

=6-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY()

Saturday of this current week:

=7-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY()

SUNDAY of following week, when Monday & not Sunday is used as day #1 of week:

=8-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY()